# Sipp Accept Encoding gzip

Tags: sip, sip-server

I am using Sipp client (http://sipp.sourceforge.net/) to test my SIP server. However when I use Accept-Encoding header with gzip value in my sipp client and print the response from the server to a log file, it writes the encoded string. Is there any way to decode the gzip data sent from the server using sipp?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to decode the data using sipp, as its dump functionality is basically for debugging. You will have to use another tool.

Comment: Thanks for the information..Could you suggest me a way to do the same? Even I was facing problem with content-Encoding.